# How to merge cells in php generated table?

Tags: php, html-table, cells

I found the solution on this site for displaying a blank cell when the xml array is repeated, but I can't seem to find an answer to merging the blank cells.

This is what I'm getting:

[image]

This is what I'd like it to look like (in terms of the merged cells):

[image]

So my question is, how do I merge those cells - tell the previous cell to use a rowspan? (alternatively, is there a way to tell the empty cells to have no border?

Here is my code:

```
<tr>
<?php if ($work_name !=$currentWork) { ?>
    <td>
    <?php 
    if ($name != $currentName) {

        echo html_encode($name);
     }

    $currentName = $name; 

    ?>
    </td>


    <td><i>
    <?php 
    if ($work_name !=$currentWork) {

      echo html_encode($work_name); 
    }

    else {

    echo " ";
    }
    $currentWork = $work_name;


    ?></i></td>                             

    <td>
    <?php 
    if ($role_attrs->name == $previousRole) {
    continue;

    }

    else {
    echo html_encode($role_attrs->name); 


    }

    $previousRole = $role_attrs->name;

    ?></td>
 </tr>
```

I hope that all makes sense!

Comment: I'm pulling it from this xml file: [link](http://andrewfinden.com/test/feed.xml). Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> alternatively, is there a way to tell the empty cells to have no border

It's much easier way, just add some class to empty cell (like `<td class="empty"> </td>` and style it in your css with `td.empty { border-top:none; }`

Answer (score 2):

`rowspan` is certainly the way to go. However, rather than spitting the HTML out as you go, you’ll need to keep track of how many rows to span and then construct the HTML accordingly.

This is an interesting problem without an *easy* solution. The problem is that `rowspan` has to reside in the first `<td>`, but you won’t know how many rows to span until *after* you’ve processed them. Your best bet is to look into PHP’s [Document Object Model](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php). The DOM will allow you to construct your table and adjust the `rowspan` attribute as needed.

A few places to start:

- [HTML DOM Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/default.asp)
- [Generating (X)HTML Documents Using DOMDocument In PHP](http://www.ultramegatech.com/blog/2009/07/generating-xhtml-documents-using-domdocument-in-php/)

### Update

This should illustrate what’s involved.

```php
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Sample</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        font: normal 62.5% sans-serif;
    }
    table {
        font-size: 1.3em;
        width: 420px;
        border: 0;
        border-collapse:collapse;
    }
    td {
        vertical-align: top;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$works = array(
    array(
        'composer' => 'HAYDN, Joseph',
        'title' => 'Die Schöpfung',
        'role' => 'Adam'
    ),
    array(
        'composer' => 'HAYDN, Joseph',
        'title' => 'Die Schöpfung',
        'role' => 'Raphäel'
    ),
    array(
        'composer' => 'HAYDN, Joseph',
        'title' => 'Il mondo della luna',
        'role' => 'Ernesto'
    ),
    array(
        'composer' => 'HAYDN, Joseph',
        'title' => 'La vera costanza',
        'role' => 'Masino'
    ),
    array(
        'composer' => 'MENOTTI, Gian Carlo',
        'title' => 'The Telephone',
        'role' => 'Ben'
    ),
    array(
        'composer' => 'MOORE, Douglas',
        'title' => 'Gallantry',
        'role' => 'Dr Gregg'
    ),
    array(
        'composer' => 'MOZART, Wolfgang Amadeus',
        'title' => 'Die Zauberflöte',
        'role' => 'Der Sprecher'
    ),
    array(
        'composer' => 'MOZART, Wolfgang Amadeus',
        'title' => 'Die Zauberflöte',
        'role' => 'Papageno'
    ),
    array(
        'composer' => 'MOZART, Wolfgang Amadeus',
        'title' => 'La nozze di Figaro',
        'role' => 'Il conte Almaviva'
    ),
    array(
        'composer' => 'NICHOLSON, Alisdair',
        'title' => 'Two sisters, a rose, a flood and snow',
        'role' => 'baritone'
    ),
    array(
        'composer' => 'OFFENBACH, Jacques',
        'title' => 'Barbe-bleue',
        'role' => 'Graf Oscar'
    ),
    array(
        'composer' => 'OFFENBACH, Jacques',
        'title' => 'La vie parisienne',
        'role' => 'Bobinet'
    ),
    array(
        'composer' => 'PUCCINI, Giacomo',
        'title' => 'La bohème',
        'role' => 'Schaunard'
    ),
    array(
        'composer' => 'PUCCINI, Giacomo',
        'title' => 'Madama Butterfly',
        'role' => 'Il principe'
    ),
    array(
        'composer' => 'PUCCINI, Giacomo',
        'title' => 'Madama Butterfly',
        'role' => 'Yamadori'
    )
);

$current_composer = '';
$current_title = '';

$composer_row_count = 1;
$title_row_count = 1;

$doc = new DOMDocument();

$table = $doc->createElement('table');
$doc->appendChild($table);

foreach($works as $work)
{
    $row = $doc->createElement('tr');
    $table->appendChild($row);

    if ($current_composer !== $work['composer']) {
        $current_composer = $work['composer'];
        $composer_row_count = 1;

        $composer_col = $doc->createElement('td', $work['composer']);
        $row->appendChild($composer_col);
    } else {
        $composer_col->setAttribute('rowspan', ++$composer_row_count);
    }

    if ($current_title !== $work['title']) {
        $current_title = $work['title'];
        $title_row_count = 1;

        $title_col = $doc->createElement('td', $work['title']);
        $row->appendChild($title_col);
    } else {
        $title_col->setAttribute('rowspan', ++$title_row_count);
    }

    $role_col = $doc->createElement('td', $work['role']);
    $row->appendChild($role_col);
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Copy the code and run it. The layout is exactly what you asked for, but naturally you’ll need to adjust it to your needs.

Comment: I found your question intriguing so I worked at a solution and updated my answer. Maybe you'll find it educational if nothing else. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="2">a cell using 2 colums</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="2">a cell using 2 rows</td>
</tr>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: But it's a PHP loop, and not everyone will need to span (see the links in my post), so I don't see how this will help...? I kind of need it to go back and see that a cell is empty and get the one above it to add the rowspan.